# Remove empty arrays? Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, string

Hello I’m using the below:

```
let str = TextField.text!
let array = str.components(separatedBy: " ")

print(array)
print(array.count)
```

> TextField input could be: “ONE TWO THREE”
>
> Which would print
>   [“ONE”, “TWO”, “THREE”]
>   3
>
> But sometimes the text input arrives as: “ONE  TWO THREE” or “ ONE TWO
>   THREE” or “ONE TWO THREE “

How can I get all the components without the empty “” ones and still have a count of 3. Rather than extra spaces accounting for extra components?

Or how can I create an array from a string containing separate words no matter how they are deprecated. I just need all the individual words out only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`split(separator:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2894564-split) instead:

```
let text = " ONE   TWO THREE  "

print(text.components(separatedBy: " "))
// ["", "ONE", "", "", "TWO", "THREE", "", ""]

print(text.split(separator: " ").map(String.init))
// ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]
```

That method has a `omittingEmptySubsequences:` parameter which is `true` by default. It returns an array of `Substring`s, which can be mapped to “real” `String`s if necessary.

Comment: Thanks guys, both answers are great and do what I need it to do. Is there a way to also change the current code to have multiple separators? So inouttext could be: “ONE, TWO” or “ ONE , TWO THREE” etc? And only the words return?

Comment: @PaulFerga: In that case you might want to use `components(separatedBy:)` with a `CharacterSet` and vadian's solution. Another approach is to use `enumerateSubstrings()` with the `.byWords` option.

Answer (score 0):

Just do *literally* what you are asking

```
var array = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
array.removeAll{$0.isEmpty}
```

Comment: Or `.filter { !$0.isEmpty }` so that you don't need a mutable variable.